How to modify single file content inside IMG file (Android) and retain similar file size after repacking?
I have folowing file (recovery.img):
https://mega.nz/file/pDUUUZIa#gKyV53CFF5fRG187fhELUh4fsh6gsyQdubT_fdW56iI
I unpacked it and overwrote file ramdisk\prop.default with file (prop.default):
https://mega.nz/file/4WNWWTwA#7-BBSYeOqOClLWC6Ncf6ynhuAI5xX7uPWwd1KUeNAp8
Then after repacking recovery.img post above minor change instead of getting recovery.img with original file size of around 24MB, repacked IMG file is only around 16MB.
What am I doing wrong here?
(For both unpacking/repacking I used AIK-Linux-v3.8-ALL.tar.gz)
